# Complex Taylor series on a simply connected domain

Tags: sequences-and-series, complex-analysis, analysis, functions

Lets say there is a simply connected domain *G* in $\mathbb{C}$ and there is a function *f* which is holomorphic on *G*. If we calculate the Taylor series around a point *a* $\in$ *G* we'd get something like $\sum_{n=0}^\infty b_n(z-a)^n$ which converges on a radius *r* around *a* because *f* is holomorphic. Is it now possible to say something about the functions behaviour on the whole domain *G*? Something like " the taylor series we calculated for *a* converges for all *z* $\in$ *G* ".
Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. For example let $G=\{z: Re\, z <1\}$. Then $G$ is simply connected and $f(z)=\frac 1 {1-z}$ is analytic in $G$. Around the point $a=0$ it has the power series expansion $\sum_n z^{n}$. But this series does not converge for $z =-2$ which belongs to $G$.

We  can only say that the power series converges in the largest disk around $a$ contained in $G$.